# Context free grammar to Chomsky normal form

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

I have a hard time understanding how to convert the following context free grammar to Chomsky Normal Form:

S $\rightarrow$ aSX | B

B $\rightarrow$ bBX | ε

X $\rightarrow$ a | b

I have a solution

S $\rightarrow$ EY | EZ | FY | FZ | ε

E $\rightarrow$ YS

F $\rightarrow$ ZB

Y $\rightarrow$ a

Z $\rightarrow$ b

that does not work and can't figure out why. Any solutions and explanations would be helpful.

Comment: How would you do a simple example like S $\rightarrow$ aSb?

Comment: S -> XQ

X -> ZS

Z -> a

Q -> b